# Is it possible to change text alignment in the middle of a string?

Tags: android, string, alignment

I would like to have the string first be aligned to the left, then the right, all in the same string. Is that possible. Have been been looking for a way to do it but can't find anything.

Example: "This is aligned to the left(some code)Now the text is aligned to the right."

Can it be done or do I need two separate textviews?

Comment: Please explain your problem briefly, you can post here its relevant screenshot too

Comment: Yes it is possible if you want to shift the whole String from left to the right and vice versa! But a whole not part of String!

Comment: Do you want part of the string to be to the left and the other part of the same string to be aligned to the right?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
val spannedText = SpannableString("some text bla-bla-bla")

val leftSpan = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
val rightSpan = AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)

spannedText.setSpan(leftSpan, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
spannedText.setSpan(rightSpan, 5, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```